# Is java socket support options like "SO_SNDTIMEO“ in C?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Currently I got a situation which client will totally disconnect without sending an EOF(Such as the client is a phone and suddenly change network for wifi to 4G), but my server will still send message to this client. This will take at least 10 mins until server found out the peer is unreachable.

So is there an option in Java to reduce sending timeout, just like the SO_SNDTIMEO in C?

Answer (score 0):

Android docs are pretty much straightforward with what they have: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html

[`SO_TIMEOUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT) is among the list, but it applies to reading operations only. Send operation completion usually doesn't indicate that a packet has been received by the remote host, but rather indicates that the packet has been accepted by kernel's network queue and will be sent "soon".

I won't blame Android team for not having (or at least not advertising) a socket option for sending timeout, because you don't get much information from completion of a `send`. It's actually up to the application level to detect disconnects. Enhance your protocol, introduce app level keepalives, try non-blocking socket mode to avoid long operations, keep track of what was actually received by a remote host - send is not enough. This will result in a much more robust application.